# setstate not updating with a dynamic key name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im not sure why my state wont update using errorOption = key + 'Error' and then setting state with [errorOption]: true. Because my formErrors state uses the same initial key as formDetails, but with 'Error' at the end so i just concatenated it. I've tried using template literals as-well, but concatenation looks easier to read here.

I want it to validate form to check for empty and change error state to true

```
const defaultData = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
}
const defaultErrorState = {
    usernameError: false,
    passwordError: false,
}

const [formDetails, setFormDetails] = useState(defaultData);
const [formErrors, setFormError] = useState(defaultErrorState);

const {
    username,
    password
} = formDetails

const {
    usernameError,
    passwordError
} = formErrors


const validateForm = (inputs) => {
    const checkThreshold = (currentValue) => currentValue.length > 0;
    let errorOption
    Object.entries(inputs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (!checkThreshold(value)) {
            errorOption = key + 'Error'
            setFormError({
                ...formErrors,
                [errorOption]: true
            })
        }
    })
    Object.entries(inputs).every(checkThreshold)
}

const handleSubmit = (event) => {

    const basicInfoValues = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    }
    if (validateForm(basicInfoValues)){
        // login stuff
    } else {alert("Fill in all fields")}

}
```

Comment: Instead of having dynamically calculated keys based on key names, just compose your state so each property is an object containing a string `value` property and a boolean `error` property.

Comment: Can you show us what `inputs` is? Maybe it is setting it as you expect, but then overwriting it in a future iteration?